# Prove if $f$ is entire and $f(\frac{1}{n^2})=f(\frac{i}{n})$ then $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove:
>   if $f$ is entire and $f(\frac{1}{n^2})=f(\frac{i}{n})$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so $f$ is constant

If $f$ is entire and $f$ is bounded so $f$ is constant according to liouville theorem

But I can not see how to prove that $f$ is bounded

Answer (score 4):

We have $f(z^2) = f(iz)$ for all $z \in A = \{\frac1{n}: n \in \mathbb N\}$ which has a cluster point. By the identity theorem, $f(z^2) = f(iz)$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$. Can you finish from here? (hint: expand $f(z)$ in power series).

Comment: You can avoid the $i$ in the functional equation by showing that $f(-z^2)=f(z)$ for $z\in\left\{\frac{i}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N\right\}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $i$ or $-1$, both are equally annoying in the expansion!

Comment: Yes. The next is easy. Not necessarily power series.

Comment: @S.Y how can we finish without power series?

Comment: @gbox for example, max{|f(z)| | |z| <= 4 } = max{|f(z)| | |z| <= 2} , then apply the maximum principle

Comment: @gbox or the same method, show f is bounded

Comment: Sorry I did not get it. we found that $f(z^2)=f(iz)$ on all $\mathbb{C}$ what can we can conclude from it?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose first $f(0)=0.$ If $f$ is nonconstant, then $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $0$ for some $m\in \mathbb N.$ Thus $|f(z)|$ is on the order of $|z|^m$ as $z\to 0.$ Therefore $|f(1/n^2)|$ is on the order of $|1/n^2|^m$ and $|f(i/n)|$ is on the order of $|1/n|^m$ as $n\to \infty.$ This contradicts our hypothesis that $f(1/n^2)=f(i/n)$ for all $n.$ Thus $f$ is constant.

If $f(0)\ne 0,$ we can apply the above to $f(z)-f(0).$ This leads to $f(z)-f(0)$ being constant, hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: This is correct too.